# How can I wait async pipe to finish and call another function after, without subscribing

Tags: angular, rxjs

Say I have this Observable:

```
public settings$: Observable<
    SettingsResponse
  > = this._service.getSettings();
```

And then I have:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
        window.customService.init();
  }
```

Because init triggers before observable is done, is there any other way to delay except setTimeout or subscribe to observable and use non async property to set settings in template, before `window.customService.init()` trigger?

Comment: Why exactly do you need `window.customService.init()` to run after the subscribe callback?

Comment: i want settings$ to be in html div before window.customService.init() triggers. you see init() depends on settings$ values to be already in DOM, when it is executed, if values are not in div tag when init runs, it fails. i used to use setTimeout, but that is very bad practice.

Comment: What do you mean by `settings$` being in DOM? Can we see how you use the observable and the `async` pipe in the template?

Answer (score 5):

You can [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) into the observable, and use [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) so that only one tab is executed for many `async` pipes.

```
public settings$: Observable<SettingsResponse> = this._service.getSettings().pipe(
                        tap(()=> this.init()), 
                        share()
                  );

public init() {
    if (!this.initFlag) {
       window.customService.init();
       this.initFlag = true;
    }
}
```

You could also use the [scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) operator and not have to track if the function has been called.

```
public settings$: Observable<SettingsResponse> = this._service.getSettings().pipe(
                        scan((acc, next)=> (acc === "first" && this.init(), next), "first"), 
                        share()
                  );

public init() {
   window.customService.init();
}
```

If you only need the *first* emitted value, then I would use the [finalize](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html) operator instead. I think it still fires with `async`, but I've never tried it.

```
public settings$: Observable<SettingsResponse> = this._service.getSettings().pipe(
                        first(),
                        finalize(() => window.customService.init()), 
                        shareReplay(1)
                  );
```

Answer (score -1):

use `tap` and execute settings$ in `ngOnInit`

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {

    this.settings$.pipe(tap(()=>window.customService.init())).subscribe()
  }
```

Comment: init() is not observable though

Comment: great, do we need to subscribe though? i only want settings$ to be in DOM before window.customService.init() triggers. you see init() depends on settings$ values to be already in DOM, when it is executed, otherwise it fails. i used to use setTimeout, but that is very bad practice.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not guarantee the order because async may take longer to complete. If you don't want subscribe you will need to create a `init$` stream which compose of `settings$` and `init()`, then <div *ngIf="$init".... to execute the subscription